# Calculating the Radon Transform from the Hartley Transform

Tags: integral-transforms

It is wellknown, that the [Radon Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) can be calculated from the [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) via the [Central Slice Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-slice_theorem).

The [Hartley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform) can be seen as a "purely real" version of the Fourier Transform and I wonder, if the Radon Transform could be calculated from the Hartley Transform in a fashion, that it is analogous to its calculation from the Fourier Transform.

> **Question:**
>
> Is there a theorem for the Hartley Transform, that is the analogue to the Central Slice Theorem for the Fourier Transform in the sense, that via that analogous theorem the Radon Transform can be calculated from the Hartley Transform in a "purely real" way, i.e. without the need for complex numbers.